# html + variable that gets date from the system

Tags: javascript, html

how do I create a variable in html and then display it here in stead of 2014.

I was thinking of getting the date using javascript and then somehow passing it here to where 2014 is.

How do I do this?

```
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. XTeam</p>
```

Comment: HTML doesn't have variables. You need to manipulate the content of that `<p>` using Javascript. Note that there are templating systems for Javascript, like AngularJS, which would allow you to write something like `&copy {{year}}. XTeam`

Answer (score 2):

You can't have variables in HTML, You can do something like bellow

Have a placeholder for `year` in your HTML.

```
<p class="text-muted">&copy; {{YEAR}}. XTeam</p>
```

and update that placeholder using javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
    var date = new Date();
    var para = document.getElementsByClassName('text-muted')[0];
    para.textContent = para.textContent.replace('{{YEAR}}',date.getFullYear());
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/72r2foc7/)

Comment: tks for this and the demo I have got this working in my example but when I do a refesh on the page I see `{{YEAR}}` before it turns to `2015` Is there away around this? I have tried putting the JS before the `</body>` tag and before the `</head>` tag but that does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: as far as I know yes. I jst put your javascript code inside my some script tags `<script>...</script>` and changed the html code to yours also.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd do this serverside, but Q&D:

```
<p class="text-muted">&copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>. XTeam</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not supported in HTML. However to achieve the functionality you are trying to achieve, you can do the following:

HTML:

```
<p class="text-muted">&copy; <span class="year"></span>. XTeam</p>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var date = new Date();
    var year = document.getElementsByClassName('year')[0];
    year.innerHTML = date.getFullYear();
}
```

Working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bo0yz47r/)

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript getDate Method</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var dt = new Date("December 25, 1995 23:15:00");
   document.write("getDate() : " + dt.getDate() ); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```